# Connecting PHP5 to a Frontbase Database

Tags: php, database, frontbase

Is there a way to connect PHP5 to a Frontbase database?

There seems to be an included connector, but it looks like that is not available anymore in PHP5:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.fbsql.php

Comment: Where does it say it's not in PHP5? You may need to compile PHP with that option or find a package with it compiled in.  It looks like it has ODBC support as well so you might be able to use that to connect with it

Comment: @Cfreak: rumors ... nothing else :)

Comment: @Cfreak: Still wondering if it is really in PHP5 - shouldn't https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=fbsql&type=Code return more matches?

Comment: I personally think that compiling your own PHP leaves you vulnerable to security hazards unless you really stay on top of all advisories. I would try going the ODBC route before before compiling. If that doesn't work then just try to compile it. You'll know real fast if it will work or not.

Comment: And yes it should compile. This page: http://php.net/fbsql_connect says it's available in PHP5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you using? What kind of PHP package are you using, i.e. if you are on *nix, are you perhaps using a prebuilt version of PHP?

If you can build your own version of PHP, you could perform the steps outlined here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/fbsql.installation.php
(i.e. you need to build PHP with the --with-fbsql parameter)

If you're on Windows, you can find prebuilt binaries for Frontbase from the frontbase.com website itself, but they seem pretty outdated (the latest one is for PHP 4):
http://www.frontbase.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/FBWebSite.woa/wa/mainFrame?currentMenu=downloadMenu&currentPage=Download&currentModule=Download&action=downloadArea

Comment: Yes, Linux (Debian or Ubuntu)